# How to fix a constantly-crashing/freezing/disconnecting VNC server?

Tags: xfce, remote-desktop, vnc, remote-x-session, tightvncserver

I am running tightvnc server on my Ubuntu machine, which I connect to from my Macbook, which then runs an XFCE virtual desktop (i.e. not the main Ubuntu desktop that shows up on the monitor connected to the server). It's able to make a connection and can keep it alive for days, but as soon as I try to open more than 1-2 programs it crashes/freezes/disconnects (just the xfce remote session, but the main Ubuntu/Gnome session remains intact). Also if I try to launch Chrome (no open tabs) it usually crashes instantaneously. I know I have enough memory - it never seems to use more than 1.5-1.75 out of the 4 GBs of RAM available. I tried reading the logs in /home/user/.vnc, but it does not add any new log info during or after a crash. What's the best way to go about debugging the problem?

Here is the tightvnc log file, but the last line in the log was written before the crash (no new lines are written during or after the crash): http://paste.ubuntu.com/13298254/